# nodejs express route resulting in error 404

Tags: node.js, express

The route is not working. I been looking for the cause and I can't find where the problem is. I keep on getting 404 error on postman with the server running.

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const items = require('./routes/api/items');

const app = express();

// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require ('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to Mongo

mongoose.connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true} )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));


  //Routes
  app.use ('api/items', items);

  const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Here is the file containing the routes. Is located at /routes/api

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


// Item Model
const Item = require('../../models/Item');

// @route   GET api/items
// @desc    Get All Items
// @access  Public
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Item.find()
      .sort({ date: -1 })
      .then(items => res.json(items));
  });

module.exports = router;
```

File models/item.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 status : Route Not found , the url you are trying that is not found

in your app js , add slash `/` before api

```
app.use('/api/items', items);
```

url will be :

http://localhost:5000/api/items

Answer (score 0):

Please understand the basic routes first.
Here is https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

When you run app like that 
http://localhost:3000 
app is runnin exactly on this url. If you route somthing else like that "api/items" this means that 
http://localhost:3000api/items.
So create any route firstly add a '/' and then it looks like 
http://localhost:3000/api/items